# Converting .lua table to a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lua

I have this kind of input:

```
    sometable = {
        ["a"] = {
            "a1",
        },
        ["b"] = {
            "b1",
            ["b2"] = true,
        },
        ["c"] = {
            "c1",
            ["c2"] = true,
        },
    },
```

And would like to convert it to some dictionary I can work with in python - or basically, I just need to be able to read the data in this pattern:

```
print sometable[b][b2]
```

What is the best solution to this? I tried to do a bunch of replaces and convert it using `ast`, ie:

```
def make_dict(input): # just body, ie. without 'sometable'
    input = input.replace("=", ":")
    input = input.replace("[\"", "\"")
    input = input.replace("\"]", "\"")
    input = input.replace("\t", "")
    input = input.replace("\n", "")
    input = "{" + input + "}"
    return ast.literal_eval(input)
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
{
 "a" : 
  {"a1", },
 "b" : 
  {"b1", "b2" : true,},
 "c" : 
  {"c1", "c2" : 1,},
}
```

The error (`invalid syntax`) is on `{"b1", "b2" : true,},`. Any suggestion?

Comment: you have to  to convert `"b1"` into `"b1":None` or something similar - dictionary can't have key without value. BTW `{"a1", }` is not dictionary but `set()` - try `print(type({"a1", })` and you get `<class 'set'>`

Comment: How would I convert `"b1"` into `"b1":None` given the function above I already mentioned? I assume some pattern matching would be used to find `"something,"` and replace it by `"something:None,"`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use it with Python? :)

Comment: Hmm, it's game related - so basically an addon in World of Warcraft saves its stuff in .lua table, and I want to run my python script on that table to calculate some values. @warspyking

Comment: I feel like a Python medium isn't necessary here, but I don't know the circumstances either so I might be entirely wrong.

Comment: Why can't you do the calculating Lua sided? @emihir0

Comment: Because then I'd have to have the game opened at all times and it is very restrictive on what I can do - ie. I can't use libraries to go make requests (web) etc... Python is just way more comfortable to code in as well for me. @warspyking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this package: https://github.com/SirAnthony/slpp.

```
>>> from slpp import slpp as lua
>>> code = """{
    ["a"] = {
        "a1",
    },
    ["b"] = {
        "b1",
        ["b2"] = true,
    },
    ["c"] = {
        "c1",
        ["c2"] = true,
    },
}"""
>>> print(lua.decode(code))
{'a': ['a1'], 'c': {0: 'c1', 'c2': True}, 'b': {0: 'b1', 'b2': True}}
```

Comment: I have trouble installing it. Ie. pip install slpp tells me that there isn't such a package, and on their github I cannot see any 'installation' guide. Any suggestion?

Comment: @emihir0, it's not on PyPI. Try this `pip install git+https://github.com/SirAnthony/slpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Another package that is both published on PyPI and more recent than slpp: https://github.com/leafvmaple/luadata

```py
import luadata

code = """{
    ["a"] = {
        "a1",
    },
    ["b"] = {
        "b1",
        ["b2"] = true,
    },
    ["c"] = {
        "c1",
        ["c2"] = true,
    },
}"""

print(luadata.unserialize(code))
```