# serialize a dict as lua table

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua

[Converting .lua table to a python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838489/converting-lua-table-to-a-python-dictionary) inquires about converting a lua table to a python dict that can be loaded with loadstring/loadfile. The [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838703/4356506) suggested a library which also supports conversion the other way around, however it is no longer maintained nor supported python3.

I was unable to find a piece of code that does this conversion anywhere.

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/appgurueu/luon for a JS implementation which could be ported to Python (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing it by myself:

```
def dump_lua(data):
    if type(data) is str:
        return f'"{re.escape(data)}"'
    if type(data) in (int, float):
        return f'{data}'
    if type(data) is bool:
        return data and "true" or "false"
    if type(data) is list:
        l = "{"
        l += ", ".join([dump_lua(item) for item in data])
        l += "}"
        return l
    if type(data) is dict:
        t = "{"
        t += ", ".join([f'[\"{re.escape(k)}\"]={dump_lua(v)}' for k,v in data.items()])
        t += "}"
        return t

    logging.error(f"Unknown type {type(data)}")
```

Comment: You should use a rope / string builder / list to append to; in its current state, this has quadratic complexity due to the linear time string concatenations.